# Rename bootstrap classes with your own name

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm developing a website for a company who don't want to appear the default bootstrap classes names on the html. Is there an easy way to change them?

For example if bootstrap has col-md-3 I want it to be custom-col-md-3.
And collapse should be custom-collapse (that can affect to the JS functions and I don't want it to happen)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Replace them all using your editor with the class name you want, then the css file also.

Comment: Find and replace all for both HTML and CSS file.

Comment: But I need the Bootstrap js still working with new classes

Answer (score 1):

it's possible.

1. Just open the SASS (LESS) sources
2. Find and replace the classes you want to rename
3. Compile that with a SASS / LESS compiler

Comment: And if I change it like that, the javaScript functions will continue working, I need them to still working with the new classes @TomasRandus

Comment: I hope that there is no JS function that operates with the grid classes.

If there is, you should do the same with JS files - to find and replace.

Comment: but there is some JS functions that operate with collapse, and the class should be custom-collapse @TomasRandus

Comment: it's possible, try to rename that and you'll see. If the sript won't works, you can fix that